# Create Tag : openstack-neutron

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, tags

Is it possible to create an `openstack-neutron` tag?

I do not have that much of reputation to do it myself.

Comment: I have created the tag and added it to http://serverfault.com/questions/676404/neutron-floating-appears-on-port-list-but-not-on-floating-ip-lists. Thanks to [this nonense](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/98950/answer-appears-automatically-converted-as-a-comment/98955#98955), I can't post this as an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@Sven it's easy to answer something like that, all you have to do is ramble on a bit and then say the job is done.

A tag for [openstack-neutron](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/openstack-neutron) has been created. Long may it be full of quality questions and $deities bless all who romp in it.

Comment: Now if only people would use it. I've seen one question already about Neutron posted today which didn't use the tag...